# Do I need to select the root category when adding a new product?

Tags: magento2, category

- Root category: Root
- Sub categories: Sub1, Sub2

When I add a new product for one of the sub categories, should I select also the root one?

Comment: No, you don't need to select root category if you want to add your assign product in sub-category. just select sub-category only.

Comment: It's you personal preference whether you want the product assign to root category or not. But assigning product to root category is not compulsory. If you want to show all products on front end or for featured products or Latest products etc, you must assign products to root category also.